# How to fetch JSON array in Laravel

Tags: php, json, laravel, laravel-5

I've a `model` in the name of `Template` and `migration table` in the name of `templates`, and i'm having a `column name` of `templatedata` in the `mysql table` which is holding the JSON array, while trying to fetch `data` in the `view` I'm getting an error,

Following is my controller:

```
  public function get_template($id)
{
    $gettemplate = Template::findOrFail($id);
    return view('nitseditor.theme', ['gettemplate' => $gettemplate]);
}
```

I'm trying to fetch the object like this:

```
@foreach($gettemplate as $template)
    <div class="branding">
         <h1 class="logo">
             <a href="index.html"><img src="{{ URL::asset($template->templatedata.content.logoimage) }}" alt="" width="25" height="26">NitsEditor</a>
         </h1>
    </div>
@endforeach
```

and following is my `JSON format` in table:

```
[{
    "content": {
            "logo": {
                    "logoimage": "img/home/nitseditorlogo.png",
                    "logolink": "index.html"
                    },
                "pages": [
                    {"pagename": "Mysite", "pagelink": "index.html"}, 
                    {"pagename": "Templates", "pagelink": "templates.html"},
                    {"pagename": "About Us", "pagelink": "aboutus.html"},
                    {"pagename": "Contact Us", "pagelink": "contactus.html"}
                        ]
                }
}]
```

I'm getting following error:

> Trying to get property of non-object (View: location of blade)

Comment: Why are you looping `$gettemplate` when it's only 1 record when you fetch it with `findOrFail($id)`?

Comment: @TheFallen I made it for `pagename` and `pagelink`, I mean, for that I need to loop.

Comment: My point is that if you loop `$gettemplate` which is a single record, you'll be looping the properties of the *Template* object, which are not objects and that's why you're getting an error.

Comment: @TheFallen, even if I remove `@foreach` and try accessing like this `$gettemplate->templatedata->content->logo->logoimage` I'm getting the same error.

Comment: Please explain what are *templatedata, content, logo, logoimage* and how are they related to the *Template* object.

Comment: @TheFallen I've a `model` in the name of `Template` and `migration table` in the name of `templates`, and i'm having a column name of `templatedata` which is holding the `JSON array`.

Comment: Try removing `templatedata` from this `$template->templatedata.content.logoimage`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this bro

```
$data_string = '[{
    "content": {
            "logo": {
                    "logoimage": "img/home/nitseditorlogo.png",
                    "logolink": "index.html"
                    },
            "pages": [
                {"pagename": "Mysite", "pagelink": "index.html"}, 
                {"pagename": "Templates", "pagelink": "templates.html"},
                {"pagename": "About Us", "pagelink": "aboutus.html"},
                {"pagename": "Contact Us", "pagelink": "contactus.html"}
                ]
            }
}]';
$template = json_decode($data_string);
echo $template[0]->content->logo->logoimage.'<br>';
echo $template[0]->content->pages[0]->pagename;
```

Result

```
img/home/nitseditorlogo.png
Mysite
```

Comment: Thanks for the update while returning $template I get the JSON, but as soon as I do $template->content I get the same error.

Comment: I'm getting the JSON return having the content inside big bracket `[{ }]`, your `JSON` contents are within `{}`, wherever I've seen the example for the contents `[{ }]` we have to place an array, for example in the above answer you have taken `pages[0]`, I tried calling through `template[0]->content`, as you can see in my question the `JSON` contents are within `[ ]` now I'm getting the error `The Response content must be a string or object implementing __toString(), "object" given.`

Comment: Your JSON is an array? Right?

Comment: Yes, it is an array.

Comment: found out the solution, thanks for the help. I've edited the answer!